# Error in exporting selected rows from Gridview to Excel

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel, gridview

I am trying to export selected columns from GridView to Excel, and every time I run the code an error pops up with some new .dll file name. What could be the issue? Please find the code below for your reference.

```
<asp:Panel ID="general" runat="server" BorderColor="#333333" BorderStyle="Double" CssClass="emailpnl" Width="800px">
    <asp:GridView ID="bestpractgrv" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnLoad="bestpractgrv_Load" CellPadding="3" GridLines="Vertical" Width="100%" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" AllowPaging="True" OnPageIndexChanging = "OnPaging">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="Gainsboro" />
    <Columns>
       <asp:TemplateField>
           <HeaderTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkboxSelectAll" runat="server" onclick="CheckAllEmp(this);" />
           </HeaderTemplate>
           <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:CheckBox ID ="boolcb" runat="server" />
           </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="idlbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("iID")%>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Discipline ID">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="discplnlbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("iDisciplineID")%>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date Created">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="dateclbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("dDateCreated")%>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Title">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="bptitlelbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("cBPTitle")%>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#000084" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#EEEEEE" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#008A8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#0000A9" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#000065" />
</asp:GridView>
    </asp:Panel>
```

**VB Code**

```
Private Sub PopulateCheckBoxArray()

        Dim CheckBoxArray As ArrayList

        If ViewState("CheckBoxArray") IsNot Nothing Then
            CheckBoxArray = DirectCast(ViewState("CheckBoxArray"), ArrayList)
        Else
            CheckBoxArray = New ArrayList()
        End If


        Dim CheckBoxIndex As Integer
        Dim CheckAllWasChecked As Boolean = False
        Dim chkAll As CheckBox = DirectCast(bestpractgrv.HeaderRow.Cells(0).FindControl("chkboxSelectAll"), CheckBox)
        Dim checkAllIndex As String = "chkboxSelectAll-" & bestpractgrv.PageIndex

        If chkAll.Checked Then

            If CheckBoxArray.IndexOf(checkAllIndex) = -1 Then
                CheckBoxArray.Add(checkAllIndex)
            End If

        Else
            If CheckBoxArray.IndexOf(checkAllIndex) <> -1 Then
                CheckBoxArray.Remove(checkAllIndex)
                CheckAllWasChecked = True

            End If

        End If

        For i As Integer = 0 To bestpractgrv.Rows.Count - 1

            If bestpractgrv.Rows(i).RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

                Dim chk As CheckBox = DirectCast(bestpractgrv.Rows(i).Cells(0).FindControl("boolcb"), CheckBox)

                CheckBoxIndex = bestpractgrv.PageSize * bestpractgrv.PageIndex + (i + 1)

                If chk.Checked Then

                    If CheckBoxArray.IndexOf(CheckBoxIndex) = -1 AndAlso Not CheckAllWasChecked Then

                        CheckBoxArray.Add(CheckBoxIndex)

                    End If

                Else

                    If CheckBoxArray.IndexOf(CheckBoxIndex) <> -1 OrElse CheckAllWasChecked Then

                        CheckBoxArray.Remove(CheckBoxIndex)

                    End If

                End If

            End If

        Next

        ViewState("CheckBoxArray") = CheckBoxArray

    End Sub
```

And I get the error on following line

```
Dim chkAll As CheckBox = DirectCast(bestpractgrv.HeaderRow.Cells(0).FindControl("chkboxSelectAll"), CheckBox)
```

This is the error message

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in App_Web_pqx0e3wy.dll but was not handled in user code

After every compilation the dll name changes, while *App_Web_XXXX.dll* remains constant

Comment: the DLL has nothing to do with this. The problem is that the object you are trying to reference was not found (i.e null). be sure to check to see if the object you are trying to find in FindControls actually exists before you start using it.

Comment: Seems like you want to retrieve the state of the checkbox on a postback/callback. Make sure that you rebind your grid before you access cells in the header of your gridview.

Comment: Thank you Ahmed Ilyas  and @Schadensbegrenzer. It worked! I had to call bindData() before PopulateCheckBoxArray(). Thanks again